# Find the New Drives connected through iSCSI

Tags: powershell, iscsi

I am writing a powerscript that connects to a target through ISCSi. I need to find the new drive letters (`F:`, `G:`, …) that is created after connecting. Is there any direct way to find that? MY script would be

```psh
New-IscsiTargetPortal -TargetPortalAddress $VirtualDeviceIp
Connect-IscsiTarget -NodeAddress $VirtualDeviceIQN
#Get the drives newly attached
```

Though not straight I tried another way of doing it.

```psh
$initial=Get-Volume
New-IscsiTargetPortal -TargetPortalAddress $VirtualDeviceIp
Connect-IscsiTarget -NodeAddress $VirtualDeviceIQN
$final=Get-Volume
#Now compare $initial and $final to find the newly attached disks
```

But I dont know implement the second idea too :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Compare](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx) the `DriveLetter` property of the two sets:

```psh
Compare-Object $initial $final -Property 'DriveLetter'
```

Expanding the property will give you just the drive letter:

```psh
$driveLetter = Compare-Object $initial $final -Property 'DriveLetter' |
               select -Expand 'DriveLetter'
```

To be on the safe side you could add a filter that restricts results to "right side" items (i.e. newly added drives), thus excluding "left side" items (i.e. removed drives):

```psh
$driveLetter = Compare-Object $initial $final -Property 'DriveLetter' |
               ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } |
               select -Expand 'DriveLetter'
```